# How to do a second transform on the output of an XSLT template

Tags: xslt

I have only basic XSLT skills so apologies if this is either basic or impossible.

I have a paginator template which is used everywhere on the site I'm looking at. There's a bug where one particular search needs to have a categoryId parameter appended to the href of the page links. *I can't alter the paginator stylesheet* or else i would just add a param to it. What I'd like to do is apply the template as is then do a second transform based on its output. Is this possible? How do others normally go about extending library templates?

So far I've thought about doing a recursive copy of the output and applying a template to the hrefs as they are processed. The syntax for that escapes me somewhat, particularly as I'm not even sure it's possible.

---

Edit - Between Dabbler's answer and Michael Kay's comment we got there. Here is my complete test.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
    <!-- note we require the extensions for this transform -->

    <!--We call the template to be extended here and store the result in a variable-->
    <xsl:variable name="output1">
            <xsl:call-template name="pass1"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!--The template to be extended-->
    <xsl:template name="pass1">
            <a href="url?param1=junk">foo</a>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--the second pass. we lock this down to a mode so we can control when it is applied-->
    <xsl:template match="a" mode="pass2">
            <xsl:variable name="href" select="concat(@href, '&amp;', 'catid', '=', 'stuff')"/>
            <a href="{$href}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <html><head></head><body>
                    <!--the node-set extension function turns the first pass back into a node set-->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($output1)" mode="pass2"/>
            </body></html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible in XSLT 2; you can store data in a variable and call apply-templates on that.

Basic example:

```
<xsl:variable name="MyVar">
   <xsl:element name="Elem"/> <!-- Or anything that creates some output -->
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$MyVar"/>
```

And somewhere in your stylesheet have a template that matches Elem. You can also use a separate mode to keep a clear distinction between the two phases (building the variable and processing it), especially when both phases use templates that match the same nodes.

Comment: And you can do the same in XSLT 1.0 with any processor that offers the exsl:node-set() extension: just replace the select in the apply-templates with select="exsl:node-set($MyVar)".

Answer (score 20):

**Here is a complete example how multi-pass processing can be done with XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="mPass2">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="mPass2"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1Result">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates mode="mPass2"
      select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1Result)/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="2*."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*" mode="mPass2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="mPass2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num/text()" mode="mPass2">
  <xsl:value-of select="3 + ."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted result (each `num` is multiplied by `2` and in the next pass `3` is added to each `num`) is produced**:

```
<nums>
   <num>5</num>
   <num>7</num>
   <num>9</num>
   <num>11</num>
   <num>13</num>
   <num>15</num>
   <num>17</num>
   <num>19</num>
   <num>21</num>
   <num>23</num>
</nums>
```