# XSL remove specific empty elements after transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

i want to remove a specific element if after transformation it contains no child

I'll rephrase the example being the closest to my real problem 
I have an paramettre let's call it "param" 
I want to delete all children of element  whose value is less than the value of "param"

and what I want is when  has no child, then  will be completely removed 
I hope I was clear

I have the following XML

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>1</c>
        <c>2</c>
    </b>
    <d></d>
</a>
```

the xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="myparam" select="4" /> 

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/a/b/c">
         <xsl:if test="text() &gt; $myparam">  
           <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result is

```
<a>
   <b/> <!-- for this example all children are less than myParam=4 so if b has no child then i want to remove it  -->
   <d/>
</a>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure your example is clear enough? To remove the element you indicated all you have to do is write an empty template for it.

Comment: But then why `<b>` and not `<d>`? Do you mean you want to remove the ones that *have* children?

Comment: thnks guys i have edited my question to be more clear about the problem

Comment: But then why is `<d>` not removed, since it also has no children? Or do you mean that you only want to remove elements that LOST children on the first transformation? In that case, we would have to save that information during the first transformation, since by looking only at the result there is no difference between `<b/>` and `<d/>`.

Comment: yes only elements that lost children after transformation but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Do you support XSLT 2.0? If so, you could use [Result Tree Fragments](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Result-Tree-Fragments) and store the intermediate result in a variable. Save the information about the nodes which had children, and then operate on the intermediate-tree you saved in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate the elements under `a` which *have* children, you could use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a/*[node()]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i don't want to remove the elements under a only if it verify some conditions so if the all child verify the condition and removed then i want the parent removed too

Answer (score 0):

Emphasis my own:

> i want to remove a specific element if **after transformation** it contains no child

In general, XSLT operates on the original XML *source*, not on its own output. What you're asking for *isn't* impossible, however. You have a few options:

1. Perform a second transformation in your host language. In other words, write one stylesheet to transform the document, then another stylesheet to perform a second pass on the first stylesheet's output.
2. Use XSLT 2 to store a node set and later operate on that
3. Use a processor that supports the `exsl:node-set()` extension to do the same thing
4. Rewrite your stylesheet to generate the desired output on the first pass. This isn't *always* possible, but sometimes it is.

More information on points two and three can be found in this question:

- [How to do a second transform on the output of an XSLT template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635593/how-to-do-a-second-transform-on-the-output-of-an-xslt-template)

Comment: thank you for the reply, i have to use xslt 1 but I will study your 3rd solution and see if it works, otherwise i'll use an other stylesheet to perform a second pass and remove the empty flag