# How to process result of previous xsl template in the xsl chain

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XSLT structure:

1) xml file which I want to process with XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ul>
    <li style="xx">option1</li>
    <li style="yy">option2</li>
    <li style="zz">option3</li>
</ul>
```

2) main XSLT template which calls two other templates:

```
...
    <xsl:include href="template1.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="template2.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:call-template name="template1"/>   
        <xsl:call-template name="template2"/>
    </xsl:template>
...
```

3) the first template(template1.xsl) is:

```
<xsl:template name="template1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//ul">        
    <xsl:copy>            
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:for-each>      
        <li>added option</li>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:copy>     
</xsl:template>
```

4) the second(template2.xsl) is:

```
   <xsl:template name="template2">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="//ul/li">        
        <xsl:copy>            
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:copy/>
            </xsl:for-each>     
            <xsl:text>PREFIX </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>
```

I expect that output XML file will contain four `<li>` tags where 'added option' should be the first and all `<li>` tags should contain prefix "PREFIX ", but instead I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ul>
    <li>added option</li>
    <li style="xx">PREFIX option1</li>
    <li style="yy">PREFIX option2</li>
    <li style="zz">PREFIX option3</li>
</ul>
```

So the problem is that the first element is added but 'template2' doesn't work for it. 
Could you please advise why this happens and how should I change my XSLT templates?

Comment: Only named templates can be called. Either there are other templates that you have not shown (and that have a `name` attribute) or there is no need to use `call-template`. Your problem would be easier to diagnose if you would show the entire stylesheets.

Comment: Also, you say that "all `<li>` tags should contain prefix "PREFIX", but instead I got", but the XML afterwards shows exactly this. How does your expected output differ from it?

Comment: I edited my question, please take a look. Yes, I expect that all `<li>` tags should contain prefix but the result XML contains `<li>added option</li>` without prefix

Comment: So, your expected output there is: `<li>PREFIX added option</li>`?

Comment: Yes, this is the desired behavior..

Comment: You need to make two passes; first pass will store the result in a variable, the second pass will process the contents of that variable. BTW, the separate documents are irrelevant to the problem, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you overcomplicate things a little bit. Considering all the information you provided, there is no need for named templates and no need for separate stylesheets.

Also note that a named template like the following:

```
<xsl:template name="template1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

does nothing more than waste disk space. If you call a template just to immediately `apply templates` (you can think of it as letting the XSLT processor call whatever template it deems appropriate) again cannot be of any use.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/ul">
       <xsl:copy>
           <li>
              <xsl:text>PREFIX added option</xsl:text>
           </li>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="li">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="li/text()">
       <xsl:text>PREFIX </xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ul>
   <li>PREFIX added option</li>
    <li style="xx">PREFIX option1</li>
    <li style="yy">PREFIX option2</li>
    <li style="zz">PREFIX option3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the structure I described is a very simplified representation of the structure of our project, unfortunately I can't change it, so that I have to use separate templates etc..

Comment: Then I don't have much hope for your project. No, seriously, to simplify your problem before posting here is the right way, but make absolutely sure to _preserve the relevant complexity_.

Comment: Besides, I don't see why you should not be able to change the organization of templates in _any_ project. You'll have to explain _why_ you need the useless named templates.

Comment: so, is it impossible to apply the template2 to the result obtained from the template1?

Comment: No, that's not possible (as I said, your named templates effectively do _nothing_) and I am quite convinced that you absolutely don't need to do that. But if you are willing to give up on your attempted solution for a moment, explain all the requirements and show a structure that is representative, I can recommend another strategy.

Comment: @MathiasMüller It *is* possible. See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635593/how-to-do-a-second-transform-on-the-output-of-an-xslt-template

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know, but you need to store intermediate results in a variable. I'm sure you understand that I try to find out what the OP really needs to accomplish before I venture into explaining multi-pass processing.