# Use intermediate results

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Suppose that on my XSLT, there is a for-each that generates one row at a time and, at the end of the iteration, generates this:

```
x0 x1
x1 x2
x2 x3
x3 x4
x3 x5
x4 x6
x5 x6
```

so I have something like this:

```
x0
|
x1
|
x2
|
x3
| \
x4 x5
| /
x6
```

How can I reproduce this? My first idea was to store the "path" of the first code to reproduce, at the and of the parsing, the graph of the second code. So, this is the reason to use variables but I know that it's an impossible way. So, my question is that if I can read the output that I produce with xslt

Comment: You are asking about your solution rather than about the underlying problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Don't start your question with "suppose" - showing an actual XML input, actual XSLT code and actual XML output will make it much clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a second transform on the output of an XSLT template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635593/how-to-do-a-second-transform-on-the-output-of-an-xslt-template)